# Writing SQL Query to Total records with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm querying data that mc.Amount is supposed to be one record, but I'm finding that users have been adding multiple records per order number.
The code below gives me my record set, but I'm having issues determining how I'd total the mc.Amount per oh.Order_Number.

All fields are the same except for mc.Amount

I believe I need a subquery, but I haven't been able to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
oh.Order_Number AS Order_Number,
od.Part_Number AS Job_Name,
od.Unit_Price AS Sale_Price,
mc.Amount AS PieceRate_Labor_Cost,
oh.Total_Labor_Cost AS Hourly_Labor_Cost,
oh.Total_Material_Cost AS Total_Material_Cost,
SUM(oh.Total_Labor_Cost + oh.Total_Material_Cost+ mc.Amount) AS 
Total_Cost,
ROUND(qbd.Profit_Percent,2) AS Profit_Percent,
od.Part_Family_Code AS FBGM,
ROUND(SUM(((od.Unit_Price - (oh.Total_Labor_Cost + 
oh.Total_Material_Cost + mc.Amount))/ 
NULLIF(od.Unit_Price,0.00))*100),2) AS Final_Margin 

FROM dbo.Order_Header oh
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Order_Detail od ON oh.Order_Header_ID = 
od.Order_Header_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Miscellaneous_Charge mc ON od.Order_Detail_ID = 
mc.Order_Detail_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Quantity_Break_Detail qbd ON mc.Order_Detail_ID = 
qbd.Order_Detail_ID

WHERE oh.Order_Number  BETWEEN  '74991' AND '75400'  AND od.Unit_Price > 
0 AND mc.Miscellaneous_Charge_Code <> 'FREIGHT'

GROUP BY 

oh.Order_Number, mc.Miscellaneous_Charge_Code, 
mc.Amount,oh.Total_Labor_Cost, oh.Total_Material_Cost, 
qbd.Profit_Percent, od.Part_Family_Code, od.Unit_Price, od.Part_Number
```

Results: (Some fields left out)

```
Order_Number: Sale_Price: PieceRate_Labor_Cost: Houly_Labor_Cost

75024       : 1890      : 43                  : 110.49

75025       : 4938      : 105.5               : 167.51

75025       : 4938      : 281.25              : 167.51

75026       : 5000      : 251.10              : 85.00

75027       : 4352      : 142.65              : 142.00

75027       : 4352      : 68.25               : 142.00

75028       : 1568      : 98.25               : 25.62
```

I'd like my final output to be:

```
Order_Number: Sale_Price: PieceRate_Labor_Cost: Houly_Labor_Cost

75024       : 1890      : 43                  : 110.49

75025       : 4938      : 386.75              : 167.51

75026       : 5000      : 251.10              : 85.00

75027       : 4352      : 210.9               : 142.00

75028       : 1568      : 98.25               : 25.62
```

Comment: Is this really MySQL? And note that '74991' is a string

Comment: Using strings to represent numeric values, and then using `BETWEEN`, is a very bad idea.  When comparing strings `'749929999'` ***is*** between `'74991'` and `'75400'`.

Answer (score 0):

seems you need sum(mc.Amount)  AS PieceRate_Labor_Cost ( and for this you should not use mc.amount in group by)

```
SELECT 
oh.Order_Number AS Order_Number,
od.Part_Number AS Job_Name,
od.Unit_Price AS Sale_Price,
sum(mc.Amount)  AS PieceRate_Labor_Cost,
oh.Total_Labor_Cost AS Hourly_Labor_Cost,
oh.Total_Material_Cost AS Total_Material_Cost,
SUM(oh.Total_Labor_Cost + oh.Total_Material_Cost+ mc.Amount) AS 
Total_Cost,
ROUND(qbd.Profit_Percent,2) AS Profit_Percent,
od.Part_Family_Code AS FBGM,
ROUND(SUM(((od.Unit_Price - (oh.Total_Labor_Cost + 
oh.Total_Material_Cost + mc.Amount))/ 
NULLIF(od.Unit_Price,0.00))*100),2) AS Final_Margin 

FROM dbo.Order_Header oh
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Order_Detail od ON oh.Order_Header_ID = 
od.Order_Header_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Miscellaneous_Charge mc ON od.Order_Detail_ID = 
mc.Order_Detail_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Quantity_Break_Detail qbd ON mc.Order_Detail_ID = 
qbd.Order_Detail_ID

WHERE oh.Order_Number BETWEEN 74991 AND 75400 AND od.Unit_Price > 
0 AND mc.Miscellaneous_Charge_Code <> 'FREIGHT'

GROUP BY 

oh.Order_Number, mc.Miscellaneous_Charge_Code, 
oh.Total_Labor_Cost, oh.Total_Material_Cost, 
qbd.Profit_Percent, od.Part_Family_Code, od.Unit_Price, od.Part_Number
```

Comment: You don't need DISTINCT with a GROUP BY.

Comment: @KenWhite True in this instance - but not strictly true, generally; they do slightly different things (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8ec78/5 - although, admittedly, a somewhat contrived example)